# What other kinds of writers are there besides plotters and pantsers?

Tags: process, terminology

In a comment to [an answer of mine](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/26822/5645) Mark Baker has suggested that the common, dichotomous view of writers as either "plotters" or "pantsers" or something of both might not be complete and that there are other types of writers.

In their extreme forms, plotters, or outliners, as they are sometimes called, construct the plot, develop the characters, and/or build their fictional world before they begin to write and during writing follow this preconceived plan, while pantsers, or discovery writers, simply sit down with no more than a seed of an idea or even no idea at all and let the story, characters, and world unfold in the process of writing. Most writers fall somewhere in between these two extremes, outlining or developing a bit and discovering the rest.

But does this description cover all kinds of writers? Is it feasible, as I did, to group worldbuilders and plotters together, or are they fundamentally different in their approach?

## What other kinds of writers are there besides plotters and pantsers?

#### Is there a better classification of writers that that dichotomous one?

*I would appreciate answers that give real life examples of writers who have described their writing process, or that cite established sources such as scholars that have studied the writing process. Please do not post mere speculation or (only) your own experience in an answer.*

Comment: An incredibly, incredibly good question

Comment: You have set some pretty stringent criteria for answers. I have read a number of writers on writing and I don't recall any of them actually reporting their method in these terms. I have read a number that recommend a steady work schedule, but I don't interpret that to mean vomiting unthought prose onto the screen. Writing is composition and transcription. You can have a regular time for composition without having to maintain a minimum typing speed. Can you give examples, of the sort you are asking for, to support the pantser/plotter dichotomy? I suspect it is a gross oversimplification.

Comment: I think *worldbuilding* is outside this scale, or orthogonal to it, because you can build a world without having a story to go with it (Tolkien famously created Middle Earth because he'd invented these languages and wanted characters to speak them), or you can build a world specifically because your characters need something to stand on during your story (David & Leigh Eddings with the Belgariad). While plotters *may* spend too much time worldbuilding or want to show it off, they don't *have* to.

Comment: Separately, do you consider @MarkBaker's "visionary" to be neither plotting nor pantsing? That's about the only thing I can think of which is not to either side of this scale — you envision the general outline or beats, but pants the creation of it. If so, Mark ought to write that answer.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I love how the **Visionary** sounds (for I am exactly that—I have a five-bullet-points outline which I never bothered to even write down, and I just keep typing to get to the next point), but it still falls under a 1% Plotter / 99% Pantser cocktail recipe, I am afraid.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum If we take worldbuilding (applied to the story, not just worldbuilding for the sake of it), we would definitely have an orthogonal scale of 100% *Skeletonists* vs. 100% *Fleshers* (the world does not have to be secondary, it can be a real one, I am talking about how much of the description is included in the narrative), but they are still somewhere on the Plotter/Pantser ruler.

Comment: @Lew If I'm understanding you, what you're descrbing (Skeleton/Flesh) is plotting/pantsing the *worldbuilding* in addition to and separate from the story itself, right?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I can see, how it can be interpreted this way, but I meant actually the opposite, referring to the writers who show (in the narrative) minimal description of the world as Skeletonists, and the ones who cannot stop until they list all the recipes of the food being served as Fleshers. The actual method of worldbuilding they employ to create the world (if it needs to be created) should be outside of the writing process, yes.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Tolkien is a particularly good example of the distinction you are making because while he spent decades on the worldbuilding, apparently without any thought of writing the story, the story itself "grew in the telling" and he apparently had not figured out what the ring was until Rivendell. And yet the tale was clearly a quest, had quest shape, even if he did not know at the beginning what the quest was for. Hypothesis: some story shapes lend themselves more to discovery writing than others.

Comment: @Lew. No, a vision is not 1% plot. It is about story shape. It is about the why of the thing and the nature of the crisis that must result from the why of the thing. A hundred different plots might serve to bring us to that crisis for that reason. I suspect the plotter (or at least the successful ones) are simply filling in the shape of the well worn and known salable story shapes. The unsuccessful ones are writing imaginary history that is not a story at all.

Comment: @MarkBaker can you elaborate on what are you referring to as *story shape* and the *imaginary history* (a bad thing, I gather) and the *why of the thing*? The plotline, the believability of the logic of the sequence of the events?

Comment: Well, I can't give an answer as I have never really worried about how other writers go about their 'job'. In fact, only very recently (in the last two years) did I come to realise there was such a marked dichotomy of plotters vs. pantsers. Some blogs I read when I first discovered the dichotomy made it sound almost like opposing appoaches and, quite honestly, I think that's too radical. Both approaches can work fine together and both have their moments in writing..

Comment: ...Although some genres may require more of one or the other, and some people may favour one or the other, it's not about which one yields the greatest advantages, but which one works for a given writer at a given moment.

Comment: @Lew There are whole books that elaborate on these things. McKee's _Story_, Vogler's _The Writer's Journey_  and EM Forsters _Aspects of the Novel_ are all useful places to look.

Comment: I don't really think there are any "other".  You have the extremes to both sides of people who either pre-plot everything and type up the plot into a story or you have the people that say f it and just start writing with just a simple idea that came into their mind.  Then you have those who are on varying degrees of that spectrum from people who slightly plot but still pants it to those who do some plotting and then pants the meat of it.  I don't believe there is another dimension to this spectrum.

Comment: This is my own method, but I thought some others might use it. I make plan, write down a plot, come up with brief character profiles, and then write the story or play. As I write ideas and characters emerge. Changes that I think would improve the text occur to me. Sometimes I have to go back and completely re-write what I have done. Sometimes I just leave myself a note in the text to do later, for example, "Change the main character to a girl." The actual writing of the original idea creates further ideas. Non-fiction is different -- argument, plan, gather evidence, combine the three.

Comment: Perhaps the problem here is that the plotter/pantser dichotomy/spectrum really only deals with plot, and really only with what you write down. Do you write a plan of your plot or do you write the plot as the story unfolds? But plot is not always the starting point. The starting point may be setting or character or a conflict that that author wishes to explore. Lewis said his stories always began with pictures -- a faun in snowy forest holding an umbrella. It we consider these different starting points and how the author proceeds from them, though, we should get a much more complex picture.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you. I'll get to those right after I am done with my current first draft. :-)

Comment: @MarkBaker: "Perhaps the problem here is that the plotter/pantser dichotomy/spectrum really only deals with plot, and really only with what you write down." I'm afraid I disagree with this particular idea. I believe character development can also fall in the spectrum. You can decide in advance (or plot) what your character is like (eg. completing a detailed quiz) or you can start with a name and discover the character as you write (pantser). And this in spite of the plot itself being previously planned or not.

Comment: Could someone please explain *pantser*?

Comment: @aparente001 A "pantser" is someone who sits down – on their pants (trousers) – and writes (without planning beforehand).

Comment: @aparente001 It comes from the phrase "[doing something] by the seat of your pants," meaning that you're winging it, or making it up as you go along, without doing any work beforehand. Another name for this is *discovery writer,* because the writer is "discovering" the story in the process of creating it. This is the opposite of a plotter, who comes up with the entire plot (to greater or lesser degree) before writing anything.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit warning:** I seem to have upset my sister (who also writes) so I've added more detail to no.2.

---

This question has been troubling me for a week now.

I met the terms - **plotter / planner** and **pantser / discoverer** - rather recently and I took an immediate dislike to their radicalism. Therefore, I ignored them. Now, @what's question has forced me to think about it.

First of all, I took to the web searching for those common 'type of writers' thingies (I include blogs, articles, infographs, cartoons, you-name-it under the concept of 'thingies').

Naturally one can't just classify writers. First we must determine what exactly we are classifying:

...by 'type of text produced'? You've got academic writers, technical writers (subtypes galore whitin that one), journalists, columnists, novelists, ... Only, no, that's not what we're classifying.

...by 'how one organises ideas for an essay'? We're getting close, but not yet. Still, you may want to take a look at [this article on the University of Notingham's website](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/studyingeffectively/studying/writer/types.aspx). It classifies essay writers in four distinct classes:

1. the **Diver**, which is basically the Pantser
2. the **Grand Plan Writer**, which is basically a research-addicted Plotter
3. the **Architect Writer**, which is a diagram-addicted Plotter
4. the **Patchwork Writer**, which kicks off with some idea, moves them around to find connections and adds more ideas as they sprout (lets call it a Pantser-Plotter hybrid)

Of course, what we want to classify is...

> how a fiction writer organises his writing (plot, characters, locations, ...)

I have no idea who originated the terms plotter / pantser (could have thought of another term for 'pantser', it always makes me think of underwear), but it's everywhere on the Internet as a great dichotomy.

@ggiaquin suggested it should be seen as less of a dichotomy and more of a spectrum. He's not alone. [This blog](https://thisnewmountain.com/2013/07/05/a-writers-approach-plotter-pantser-hybrid/) mentions the *hybrid* for those that get caught somewhere in the spectrum. But it still doesn't satisfy me.

The British author Zadie Smith delivered [a lecture](https://www.brainpickings.org/2014/09/12/zadie-smith-writing-that-crafty-feeling/) in 2008 which shows she sticks with the dichotomy, rather than the spectrum, but she gives it nicer (IMHO) names: **macroplanner** (or plotter) and **micromanager** (or pantser).

I picked those terms and broke them apart to create five different classes of writers.

---

1. the **planner**, generally speaking, dislikes chaos. He's organised and neat. Therefore he wants his work to be structured, but how much so?

1.1 the **macroplanner** works with large scale plans: events, characters, places, everything is mapped, thought over, analysed and adjusted in order for the whole machine (read 'novel') to work with absolute precision. There may be little surprises along the way but they'll tend to be seen as rebellions to be quickly submitted. The characters do not control the writer. Ever.

1.2 the **microplanner** works with small scale plans. Most likely, most elements are carefully pre-crafted (say, events) while others are only partially fleshed out (say, characters). Or perhaps the main plot and the main character are carefully decided in advance and the subplot gets relative freedom to do as please (within clear boundaries, naturally). Characters may take a life of their own on occasion but the writer will quickly remind them to behave and conform.

---

3. the **manager**, generally speaking, dislikes restrictions. He's flexible and deals with what comes when it comes if it comes. He's laid-back and craves the excitement of discovery. He wants his work to come forth naturally, but how much so?

3.1 the **micromanager** starts with chaos (at least I tend to see nothingness as a face of chaos) and gives it order. Literally. He starts with an idea, or a vision (like a picture, a scene or a dialogue), and then he lets things evolve. The story is already there, he just needs to uncover it. The characters rule. Until a certain moment where order starts to descend back into chaos (the traditional chaos of too much disorganised information). Then the writer stops, organises all the information that has come forth so far and may or may not take the moment to trace an outline of what has happened so far. Then he can continue, bravely on, to where no Man has gone before.

3.2 the **macromanager** works amidst chaos, from the nothingness type of chaos to the tornado of information type. The characters are encouraged to take a life of their own and do as they will. In the worst case scenario, the writer will write down a random scene of daily life to learn a bit more about the character before sending it into the novel itself (or during a break).

---

A bit unsequentially, let's talk about no. 2...

2. the **hybrid** or the **planning manager** is a writer that needs plans and chaos in more or less equal measure but in different places. He may start with several plot points that are very detailed within themselves but are disconnected from one another; then, while writing, he'll discover how to connect them. Or maybe his characters allways start out with a couple of impressionistic strokes that the writing will give greater definition to later on. Or maybe he carefully plans a first part where B must cause A to happen and can't plan anything beyond it until he has finished the section and both characters and events have opened some much needed (and previously hidden) doors. Then he can go back to the designing table and decide the details of the next big plot point.

2.1 the **top-down** planning manager plans a big arc (or big picture) in detail. A must happen exactly this way so that B can then do exactly that. The little things under that arc? We'll see as they come.

2.2 the **down-top** planning manager plans key events in details and determines a set of restrictions that must be respected. As the story evolves, a bigger picture will slowly emerge.

2.3 the **plot-first** planning manager plans the setting and the main events in detail, then creates the character and lets them do as they wish in the fictional world (think an RPG with a laid-back GM that gives the PCs free reign to explore the world and choose their battles).

2.4 the **character-first** planning manager previously creates an intricately detailed character and gives it a deep problem. Then lets it search for a solution. Imagine: a parent overcome by grief at the loss of their only son trying to find a meaning to life.

---

---

*PS: I apologise for not following PC but I'm an old school female who can accept that 'he' works just fine to refer to all the biological and psychological genders in the world (my native language makes it even more naturally so than English).*

*PPS: I had a British teacher when I first learned the clothes vocabulary so 'pants' will always mean 'underwear' for me. And, yes, 'pantser' does make me picture a person sitting at one of those swivel office chairs in their underwear. And if you have ever sat on one of those in summer while wearing shorts, you know doing so in underwear is beyond uncomfortable.*

Answer (score 5):

I suggest we also have **"The Expander"**

You asked for something other then "Plotters" or "Pantsers".  I would venture to offer the "Expander".  An author who writes notes and even entire unpublished stories about off screen characters that they never intend to do more than refer to in a few short throwaway lines. (Or sometimes mean to come back to but either struggle or fail utterly at the return)

3 examples:
David Eddings

He described his (& Leigh's) writing style quite a bit.

He wrote several sweeping Fantasy epics - for the Young adult market.

IIRC He described in the forward to one of his books "The Rivan Codex" that he wrote a significant backstory, fleshed out quite a lot of the basic plotline - but the characters went their own way.

What I am suggesting is that one of the best writers of our age wrote a plot. Fleshed out some pretty significant backstory - and then found the story departed into a life of it's own.  Largely following the plot outline the author had set but deviating in some specific points. Sufficiently that the already written backstory in some parts was now incorrect.

Another author I know - L E Moddessit - has stated he will sometimes write a backstory around a particular character who may never even appear directly in the story.

JRR Tolkien is perhaps the most famous example - some of the notes he made have now been published as "Unfinished Tales and The History of Middle-earth" along with some other volumes.

Comment: That only divides the plotters into those that do and those that don't stick to their plotting. It doesn't mean that their approach is fundamentally different. Those that do deviate from their plotting are using their outline to discovery write.

Comment: Fair enough - although I do think that writing a plot outline and then moving in a different direction qualifies as being something distinctly different from the 2 extremes of plotter and pantser.

Comment: I wouldn't say "distinctly different", that is, not some third, but a hybrid along the dimension between plotter and pantser.

Answer (score 1):

I would say **poets** deserve their own category. (I also like the fact it starts with a *P*.)

If plotters plot and pamtsers wing it, then poets mosey along at their own pace. They are not simply a combination thereof.

Plenty of storytellers are poetic at points or in entirety. such as Shakespeare and Homer. I would guess part of their  prose was added or deleted in whatever editing style they adhered to simply to improve on the poetic quality. Some poets, such as e e cummings, are frequently more concerned with the sounds than the words themselves. Story is almost secondary.

Answer (score 0):

You can set yourself a problem and then set out to solve it.  Similar to how a modern composer might choose a 12 tone row and then start working with it.  When you do this, as you play with your row, you manipulate it and transform it.  For example, you might define certain characters or a certain conflict, and then put your characters on the chess board together and see what happens.  And let's remember that a place can also be a character.  Your plot can be subservient to figuring out, and demonstrating, who your characters are.

You can set yourself a goal, i.e. set up a milestone (that might end up being the midpoint or the endpoint, etc.) and then start writing towards it, either forwards or backwards or both.

You can have something in mind, such as a certain nostalgic feeling, or a feeling of magical realism, or a soothing feeling of keeping to a predefined formula (that is defined based on other elements besides just plot), or a certain type of silliness, or some stepping stones that you want to visit, etc., etc., and then try this and that to achieve what you're aiming for.

You could in principle set up a challenge for yourself of a certain prescribed omission.  Like a movie from a while back, whose name I can't remember, in which a main character never appeared in a scene.

You could start with an unexpected combination of clichés and see where it gets you.

Those are just a few ideas that occur to me about the infinite number of ways you can set out the elements you wish to work with.